# False statement? $|x| < \frac{1}{\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} \Longrightarrow \Sigma a_n x^n$ is uniformly convergent?

Tags: calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

I saw this theorem in Calculus book:

> Let $\alpha = \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$, $R = \frac{1}{\alpha}, 0 < R^{'} < R$.
>
> $|x| \leq R^{'}\Longrightarrow \Sigma a_n x^n$ is uniformly convergent.

Please tell me an example in which this statement is not true:

> $|x| < R\Longrightarrow \Sigma a_n x^n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Take the easiest series of all, $\sum x^n$. The series converges on $(-1,1)$, but the convergence isn't uniform on the entire interval; it is uniform only on compact subsets of $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. symplectomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

The power series IS uniformly convergent on $\{x: |x|\leq R'\}$.

In the case $0\ne R \ne \infty,$ and $0<R'<R$ we have $1/R'>1/R=\lim \sup_n|a_n|^{1/n}.$ So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $(1/S)^n>|a_n|^n,$ where $S=(R+R')/2.$ So there exists $n_0$ such that, for all $x$ for which  $|x|\leq R' ,$ we have $$n>n_0\implies |a_nx^n|\leq (R'/S)^n.$$  Note that $R'/S$ is independent of $x$ and that $0<R'/S<1.$

$R=\infty$ means $\lim_n |a_n|^{1/n}=0.$ If $R=\infty$ and $\infty>R'>0$ take $n_0$ such that  $n>n_0\implies |a_n|^{1/n}<1/(2R').$ Then for all $x$ such that $|x|\leq R'$ we have $$n>n_0\implies |a_nx^n|\leq 2^{-n}.$$

Note that all of the above applies verbatim in $\Bbb C$ as well as in $\Bbb R.$ A similar argument shows that $\sum_na_nx^n$ diverges if $|x|>R.$

The power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ converges to $\frac {1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ but does not converge uniformly on $\{x : |x|<1\}:$ Let $x_M=\frac {1}{2^{1/(M+1)}}.$ Then  $$\sup_{|x|<1}\left|\left(\sum_{n=0}^Mx^n\right)-\frac {1}{1-x}\right|=$$ $$=\sup_{|x|<1}\frac {|x^{M+1}|}{|1-x|}\geq$$ $$\geq  \frac {|(x_M)^{M+1}|}{|1-x_M|} =$$ $$=\frac {1/2}{1-x_M}>1/2    .$$

Comment: We can also say that since $\sup_{|x|<1}\sum_{n=0}^Mx^n=M+1$ but $\sup_{|x|<1}  \left|\frac {1}{1-x}\right|=\infty,$  therefore the sup of the absolute difference of these two expressions must be $ \infty.$

Comment: The formula for R is called the Cauchy-Hadamard radius formula.

Comment: There are  theorems concerning convergence (or not) of the series  when  |x|=R   but I am not very familiar with them.